# .NET Micro Framework Unsafe code

Tags: c#, unsafe, .net-micro-framework

Does .NET Micro Framework support unsafe code? In other words, can I use pointers in my code for .NET Micro Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Micro_Framework) (emphasis mine):

> For example, the platform does not
>   support symmetric multiprocessing,
>   multi-dimensional arrays,
>   machine-dependent types, or **unsafe
>   instructions**.

The [technical white paper](http://www.scribd.com/doc/92575985/NET-Micro-Framework-White-Paper) lists it in the omitted features too.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Thanks, changed it to a scribd one.

Comment: Although this is an ancient question (in SO time), I have added an answer which shows that the `unsafe` keyword apparently works at present, although it remains a documented "unsupported" feature.

Comment: @nicholas: I suspect it was introduced in a later version.

Comment: possibly. i can find no documentation stating that it is a supported feature (or unsupported for that matter). hard to say when it was added

Comment: While it works it's rather unreliable, even in 4.3
For example [var result = \*(((short\*)numRef));] will retrieve 2 bytes on the desktop but only one on the micro framework. We found that out the hard way ...

Answer (score 1):

Although officially not supported, I have personally used and tested unsafe code in NETMF 4.2 and find that it works as expected.

Another developer provides sample code for implementing a `BitConverter` class on NETMF doing just this:

http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/topic/308-bitconverter/